# Increasing disk space of Kubernetes Jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, architecture, microservices, system-design

We are setting up a Jenkins system with is using Kubernetes pods as Jenkins slave. The problem we are facing is that we create a pod, the pods that get a disk storage of 10GB are mapped to the root. As per our application design this gets exhausted soon and we run out of space. I checked the Kubernetes configuration in the Jenkins but it does not support any feature to specify the disk storage.

Can anyone suggest how can we increase this storage space? Also is this possible or not?

Comment: how you are installing the jenkin ? using helm ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a persistent volume for Jenkins slave of the size that you actually need. Depends on how you are deploying the slaves on Kubernetes (simple yaml, helm, any other), you can specify the size and volume accordingly.

Comment: Using a persistent volume would be a good option. But I am more curious about how the threshold of 10 GB is set

Comment: You can change it, you just figure out which directory is taking all the spaces and then mount it on a pv of the size you chose

Answer (score 0):

if you are using installing jenkin using helm over kubernetes please just update the variable inside value.yaml

Helm chart : https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins

Variable to update : `persistence.size`

Default size if 8 GB however you can increase it as per need.

Comment: We have installed jenkins on a Virtual machine and then using kubernetes configuration in it to define the pod definition. Still would we need to change the value of ' persistence.size'

Comment: if you want to increase the size of disk I think you might require the change the disk size.